# How to create Strings from a JTable txt file?

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing, jtable

I need to read from a txt file and sort everything in different arrays or strings, allowing me to set text for my JLabels. One array/string for ID, Item Name, Price and Stock.

[image]

This is a preview of my txt file:

[image]

Here is my code to read the txt file to import it to my JTable:

```
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\zagad\\IdeaProjects\\DATABYTES\\stock\\consoles\\consoles.txt";
                File file = new File(filePath);
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String firstLine = br.readLine().trim();
                    String[] columnsName = firstLine.split(", ");

                    DefaultTableModel model3 = (DefaultTableModel) productTable.getModel();
                    model3.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);

                    Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++) {
                        String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
                        String[] dataRow = line.split("/");

                        model3.addRow(dataRow);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

How do I separate them? Any help would be appreciated.

TXT FILE:

```
ID      , Item Name              ,Price     , Stock
00016   / Apple Airpods          / 8999     / 20
00017   / Samsung Galaxy Buds    / 6999     / 13
00018   / Apple Airpods Pro      / 14999    / 5
00019   / Beats Powerbeats Pro   / 13490    / 8
00020   / Sony WF-1000XM3        / 10799    / 10
```

Comment: Can you provide the text file and not an image of the text file

Comment: @Jason Hello! How can I do that here in stockoverflow? I'm new here. Thank

Comment: You can simply copy your text file and place it into a code block like you have with the other segments.

Comment: @Jason Here you go :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the format separates each of the columns by `\` so you can split the String by that. What we can do is read all lines from a given Path object which is the Path to the file. We can then skip the first line which we know is the table column names. We can then map each of these lines which are individual String objects to a String array by removing all whitespace with the replaceAll reference and then use the String#split method to split the line by `\` which will give us each of the columns for each row. We can then collect all of these String arrays to a List using the Stream#collect method.

```
         List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("first.txt"));

        String[] columnNames = lines.stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(IOException::new).split(",");

        List<MyRow> rows = lines
                .stream()
                .skip(1)
                .map(line -> line.replaceAll(" ", "").split("/"))
                .map(MyRow::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        DefaultTableModel model3 = new DefaultTableModel();

        model3.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

        rows.forEach(row -> model3.addRow(new Object[] { row.getId(), row.getItemName(), row.getPrice(), row.getStock() }));

        List<Integer> ids = rows.stream().map(MyRow::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[00016, AppleAirpods, 8999, 20]
[00017, SamsungGalaxyBuds, 6999, 13]
[00018, AppleAirpodsPro, 14999, 5]
[00019, BeatsPowerbeatsPro, 13490, 8]
[00020, SonyWF-1000XM3, 10799, 10]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more about this code? Would really help, thank you!

Comment: Absolutely, one moment.

Comment: How can I insert this code to my existing code? as I am new with the Stream#collect method :(

Comment: What is the DefaultTableModel? If it's custom provide it in the main post in code tags.

Comment: Updated, try that.

Comment: Oh I seem to get your format, but I would like to separate each one into separate string/array. Like one array for ID?

String ID = {00016, 00017, 00018, 00019, 00020}

Comment: Okay so what you might want to do is think about converting these rows into POJOs. Then you can filter through those pojos and find all ids, or any other column.

Comment: No problem man, i can update it if you want with how to do that.

Comment: Would appreciate it bro :)

Comment: Hey, I edited it. We essentially take the String array now and map to a new object, MyRow using the MyRow#valueOf method which takes a String array and parses it to a MyRow object. We then can get all ids simply by taking all rows and mapping by the getId() method of MyRow and collecting to a List.